# Best Fit Distribution Plotting

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I plot a linear graph of `df1` and want to create a distribution fit graph of `df1`. I have used the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import scipy.stats

x = scipy.arange(df1)
y = scipy.int_(scipy.round_(scipy.stats.vonmises.rvs(5,size=size)*47))
h = plt.hist(y, bins=range(48))

dist_names = ['gamma', 'beta', 'rayleigh', 'norm', 'pareto']

for dist_name in dist_names:
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
    param = dist.fit(y)
    pdf_fitted = dist.pdf(x, *param[:-2], loc=param[-2], scale=param[-1]) * size
    plt.plot(pdf_fitted, label=dist_name)
    plt.xlim(0,47)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, after running this code, I received the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Please assist me. TQ

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not embed data as images, only as text. Data types may differ although they appear similar in the image.

Comment: When you report a Python error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, str_rep)
    148     try:
--> 149         result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, left, right)
    150     except TypeError:

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr)
    207     if use_numexpr:
--> 208         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)
    209     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
    120     if result is None:
--> 121         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    122

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
     69     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
---> 70         return op(a, b)
     71

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-f2ddb3e884b0> in <module>
      3 import scipy.stats
      4 #size = 3000
----> 5 x = scipy.arange(df1)
      6 y = scipy.int_(scipy.round_(scipy.stats.vonmises.rvs(5,size=size)*47))
      7 h = plt.hist(y, bins=range(48))

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/_lib/deprecation.py in call(*args, **kwargs)
     18             warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning,
     19                           stacklevel=stacklevel)
---> 20             return fun(*args, **kwargs)
     21         call.__doc__ = msg
     22         return call

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)
    781                 self = self.fillna(fill_value)
    782 
--> 783             new_data = dispatch_to_series(self, other, op, str_rep)
    784             return self._construct_result(new_data)
    785

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in dispatch_to_series(left, right, func, str_rep, axis)
    379         # Get the appropriate array-op to apply to each block's values.
    380         array_op = get_array_op(func, str_rep=str_rep)
--> 381         bm = left._data.apply(array_op, right=right)
    382         return type(left)(bm)
    383

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, filter, **kwargs)
    438 
    439             if callable(f):
--> 440                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    441             else:
    442                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in apply(self, func, **kwargs)
    388         """
    389         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
--> 390             result = func(self.values, **kwargs)
    391 
    392         if is_extension_array_dtype(result) and result.ndim > 1:

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in arithmetic_op(left, right, op, str_rep)
    195     else:
    196         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
--> 197             res_values = na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
    198 
    199     return res_values

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, str_rep)
    149         result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, left, right)
    150     except TypeError:
--> 151         result = masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
    152 
    153     return missing.dispatch_fill_zeros(op, left, right, result)

Comment: ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
    110         if mask.any():
    111             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
--> 112                 result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], y)
    113 
    114     result, _ = maybe_upcast_putmask(result, ~mask, np.nan)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: The above is the error that I get when I run the code. It was a very long error.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you add the traceback to the question instead of putting it in the comments.   You should be able to edit your own question.